# PCA, how to add the zero axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am trying to draw the two horizontal and vertical lines at 0.00 point using ggplot2,
I have tried this

```
theme <-
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_line(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line()
)
ggplot(data=eigenvec) + geompoint() + theme
```

[image]

I want only the two lines at 0.0, not the whole grid, how can I have that?

eigenvector data

| PC1 | PC2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.651002 | -0.613762 |
| -0.52076 | -0.21174 |
| -0.482915 | -0.202607 |
| 0.108556 | 0.439427 |
| 0.244979 | 0.586785 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You manually added a grid with `panel.grid.major` which you should remove, and then you have to draw the lines at the coordinates you want with `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` :

```
theme <-
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_line(),
    axis.line.y = element_line())
ggplot(data=eigenvec,aes(x=PC1,y=PC2)) + geom_point() + theme +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+ geom_vline(xintercept=0)
```

(Pay attention that the code you shared was plenty of errors on ggplot formatting)

[image]